# Writing a small C program to shutdown windows in entered time

Tags: c, windows

I want to write a program to shut down windows in `N` seconds. The easiest method I know to shutdown windows is to call `system()` with

```
shutdown -s -t XXXX
```

where XXXX is the given time. However `system()` only accepts string as a parameter. How can I call `system("shutdown -s -t 7200")` where 7200 is inputed by the user?

Comment: `system` isn't really the best way to do this. Simply call [`InitiateSystemShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: so where are you stuck?   Getting the user input?  Appending it as a string to the system call?  Somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`InitiateSystemShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873.aspx) instead. You *could* use `ExitWindows` or `ExitWindowsEx`, but neither of those directly supports the delay being asked about in the original question, so you'd have to add code to do that delaying (e.g., using `SetTimer`). That's certainly possible, but incurs extra work without accomplishing anything extra in return.

If you insist on using `system`, you can use `sprintf` (or something similar) to create the string you pass to `system`:

```
char buffer[256];

sprintf(buffer, "shutdown -s -t %d", seconds);
system(buffer);
```

Comment: I think to call ExitWindows the OP would need elevated rights, otherwise +1.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Nearly *anything* that attempts to shutdown the computer needs the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege, whether done via InitiateSystemShutdown, ExitWindows(Ex), or `shutdown` on the command line. Although it was edited in, I would recommend against ExitWindows(Ex) under the circumstances. To use them after a delay, you'd have to handle the delay part yourself -- extra work for no gain.

Comment: I believe [`shutdown` does that internally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376881.aspx) is all I'm pointing out.

Comment: It's pretty unusual for a user not to have sufficient rights to shut the machine down.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What (I think) he's pointing out is that you have to enable the privilege before using it. It's true, and I suppose it might (just possibly) be a line or two longer than the code to do sprintf safely, but certainly not much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html) and [`sprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sprintf.html), e.g.:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 50
/* ... */
int shutdownTime;
char shutdownCall[MAX_LENGTH];

scanf("%d", &shutdownTime);
if (shutdownTime < 0) 
    return NEGATIVE_TIME_ERROR;
sprintf(shutdownCall, "shutdown -s -t %d", shutdownTime);
system(shutdownCall);
```